# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/saxpath/SAXPathException

Tags: sax, noclassdeffounderror

In my app, in runtime I was getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jaxen/NamespaceContext`

So after looking into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058158/jdom-working-with-xpath) thread I added `dom4j.jar` and `jaxen.jar` to my classpath using maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>full</version>
    </dependency>
```

After dong that I have encountered a differnt exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/saxpath/SAXPathException
```

I was not able to locate any proper solution.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include **[dom4j-1.6.1.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar)**.

Since you are mapping to the version 1.6.1